# Shortcut to open folder in favorite list in Dopus

Tags: directoryopus

In Dopus, `Alt-A` open favorite list, ArrowUp and ArrowDown to select folder. Is it possible to open folder by typing first letters?

Example: If I have a `project` folder, and nothing else starts with `p`, type `p` to open `project`.

If this is impossible, is there a quicker way other than Arrow Up/Down selection?